# Got Error: DeveloperError Exception of type 'Google.GoogleSignIn+SignInException' was thrown --- unity, firebase, google login?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, exception, error-handling, google-signin

I am developing an app in unity. I use the firebase google login method. basically google login is working and the user was listed in google firebase users log after login. the problem is, it is throwing an error. because of this can't fetch data from the firestore. even without firestore code, the app is showing the error

> Got Error: DeveloperError Exception of type
> 'Google.GoogleSignIn+SignInException' was thrown

what may be the problem.

below is my code

```
 public class GoogleSignInDemo : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Text infoText;
        private string webClientId = "xxxxxxaaaaaaabbbb.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    
        private FirebaseAuth auth;
        private GoogleSignInConfiguration configuration;
    
        private void Awake()
        {
            configuration = new GoogleSignInConfiguration { WebClientId = webClientId, RequestEmail = true, RequestIdToken = true };
            CheckFirebaseDependencies();
        }
    
        private void CheckFirebaseDependencies()
        {
            FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.IsCompleted)
                {
                    if (task.Result == DependencyStatus.Available)
                        auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
                    else
                        AddToInformation("Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + task.Result.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    AddToInformation("Dependency check was not completed. Error : " + task.Exception.Message);
                }
            });
        }
    
        public void SignInWithGoogle() { OnSignIn(); }
        public void SignOutFromGoogle() { OnSignOut(); }
    
        private void OnSignIn()
        {
            GoogleSignIn.Configuration = configuration;
            GoogleSignIn.Configuration.UseGameSignIn = false;
            GoogleSignIn.Configuration.RequestIdToken = true;
            AddToInformation("Calling SignIn");
    
            GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignIn().ContinueWith(OnAuthenticationFinished);
        }
    
        private void OnSignOut()
        {
            AddToInformation("Calling SignOut");
            GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignOut();
        }
    
        public void OnDisconnect()
        {
            AddToInformation("Calling Disconnect");
            GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.Disconnect();
        }
    
        internal void OnAuthenticationFinished(Task<GoogleSignInUser> task)
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                using (IEnumerator<Exception> enumerator = task.Exception.InnerExceptions.GetEnumerator())
                {
                    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        GoogleSignIn.SignInException error = (GoogleSignIn.SignInException)enumerator.Current;
                        AddToInformation("Got Error: " + error.Status + " " + error.Message);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddToInformation("Got Unexpected Exception?!?" + task.Exception);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                AddToInformation("Canceled");
            }
            else
            {
                AddToInformation("Welcome: " + task.Result.DisplayName + "!");
                AddToInformation("Email = " + task.Result.Email);
                AddToInformation("Google ID Token = " + task.Result.IdToken);
                AddToInformation("Email = " + task.Result.Email);
                SignInWithGoogleOnFirebase(task.Result.IdToken);
    
                SceneManager.LoadScene(1); //Savad - Load Welcome screen when Google Login
            }
        }
    
        private void SignInWithGoogleOnFirebase(string idToken)
        {
            Credential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential(idToken, null);
    
            auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                AggregateException ex = task.Exception;
//==============Here is the problem
                if (ex != null)
                {
                    if (ex.InnerExceptions[0] is FirebaseException inner && (inner.ErrorCode != 0))
                        AddToInformation("\nError code = " + inner.ErrorCode + " Message = " + inner.Message);
//=======================================
                }
                else
                {
                    AddToInformation("Sign In Successful.");
                }
            });
        }
    
        public void OnSignInSilently()
        {
            GoogleSignIn.Configuration = configuration;
            GoogleSignIn.Configuration.UseGameSignIn = false;
            GoogleSignIn.Configuration.RequestIdToken = true;
            AddToInformation("Calling SignIn Silently");
    
            GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignInSilently().ContinueWith(OnAuthenticationFinished);
        }
    
        public void OnGamesSignIn()
        {
            GoogleSignIn.Configuration = configuration;
            GoogleSignIn.Configuration.UseGameSignIn = true;
            GoogleSignIn.Configuration.RequestIdToken = false;
    
            AddToInformation("Calling Games SignIn");
    
            GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignIn().ContinueWith(OnAuthenticationFinished);
        }
    
        private void AddToInformation(string str) { infoText.text += "\n" + str; }
    
        public void SwitchToPhoneSignup()
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
        }
    
        public void SwitchToOtp()
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
        }
        public void SwitchToEmailSignUP()
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just guessing but if your app is not using a secure connection you probably have to check the less-secure access 
https://myaccount.google.com›lesssecureapps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of Google SignIn code w/ Firebase Authentication and GoogleSignIn libraries:

```cs
    private void SignInWithGoogle(bool linkWithCurrentAnonUser)
       {
          GoogleSignIn.Configuration = new GoogleSignInConfiguration
          {
             RequestIdToken = true,
             // Copy this value from the google-service.json file.
             // oauth_client with type == 3
             WebClientId = "[YOUR API CLIENT ID HERE].apps.googleusercontent.com"
          };
    
          Task<GoogleSignInUser> signIn = GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignIn();
    
          TaskCompletionSource<FirebaseUser> signInCompleted = new TaskCompletionSource<FirebaseUser>();
          signIn.ContinueWith(task =>
          {
             if (task.IsCanceled)
             {
                signInCompleted.SetCanceled();
             }
             else if (task.IsFaulted)
             {
                signInCompleted.SetException(task.Exception);
             }
             else
             {
                Credential credential = Firebase.Auth.GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential(((Task<GoogleSignInUser>)task).Result.IdToken, null);
                if (linkWithCurrentAnonUser)
                {
                   mAuth.CurrentUser.LinkWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(HandleLoginResult);
                }
                else
                {
                   SignInWithCredential(credential);
                }
             }
          });
       }
```

The parameter is for signing in with intentions of linking the new google account with an anonymous user that is currently logged on. You can ignore those parts of the method if desired. Please note all of this is called after proper initialization of the Firebase Auth libraries.

Source: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity

The readme page contains a step-by-step instructions for getting this setup for your environment. After following those and using the code above, you should have this working on both android and iOS.

Here is the `SignInWithCredential` method used in the code above:

```
    private void SignInWithCredential(Credential credential)
       {
          if (mAuth != null)
          {
             mAuth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(HandleLoginResult);
          }
       }

`mAuth` is a reference to FirebaseAuth:

    mAuth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
```

Comment: What is HandleLoginResult??

Answer (score 1):

For someone asking for the HandleLoginResult from @DIGI Byte, here is the code, feel free to remove try/catch block for debug purpose:

```
 private void HandleLoginResult(Task<FirebaseUser> task)
        {
            try
            {
                if (task.IsCanceled)
                {
                    UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync was canceled.");
                    return;
                }
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception.InnerException.Message);
                    return;
                }
                else
                {

                    FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
                    UnityEngine.Debug.Log($"User signed in successfully: {newUser.DisplayName} ({newUser.UserId})");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (e != null)
                {
                    UnityEngine.Debug.Log(e.InnerException.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: While this comment may help, it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have Error like: `got error developer error exception of type 'google.googlesignin+signin exception' was thrown`?

APK and AAB file have different SHA1 and SHA256. In Firebase, it's best to add SHA for both applications.

You can check the SHA from the AAB file in **Google Play Console** -> **Your application** -> **Configuration** -> **Application integrity** -> **Application signing**.
I added these SHA keys to Firebase and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

**Get SHA-1 and SHA-256 from the .aab file uploaded on the play store**
Google Play Console -> Your application -> Configuration -> Application integrity -> Application signing

**Get SHA-1 and SHA-256 using following command from the keystore you are using while preparing build**
keytool -list -v -keystore "path\debug.keystore" -alias aliasname -storepass keystorepassword -keypass aliaspassword

Run above command where your JDK installed and keytool.exe placed.
i.e. C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.30f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin

**Once you have SHA keys from .aab and keystore, then add those under the firebase app setting** check attached screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPAnZ.png)